# Chrome save auto opened pdf

Tags: google-chrome

When I click on a link that leads to a PDF file (e.g. in search results), Chrome automatically opens this file in a new tab. That is fine.

Now if I looked through the file and want to save it on my hard drive, I click 'Save page as...' and the downloading starts. But to show the file in a tab shouldn't Chrome have already downloaded it and probably saved to temp folder or smth. Is this correct? Can I prevent re-downloading of the file and make Chrome just copy it to a different location?

I have Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit)
on Mac OS X 10.10.3

Comment: You are assuming the Chrome PDF viewer downloads the entire file to show it to you, when it probably doesn't.

Comment: Where does it store the file then? When the file is large I can see the circular progress bar appearing in the lower left corner.